# Problem with resetting for loop when reading over csv files

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement

In my code for an NBA simulation which allows the user to select 2 teams from the same or different seasons. If the user selects both teams from the 2019-20 season then the team 1 point array and opponent 1 point array is filled but the team 2 and opponent 2 arrays are empty. Every other combination of seasons and teams work e.g. team 1 from 2019-20 and team 2 from 2015-16. I'm pretty sure the issue is to do with the for loop in the if statement checking if the season2 is equal to 2019-20.

```
import csv
from nba_api.stats.static import teams
import random as rnd
import numpy as np

team1_search = teams.find_teams_by_full_name('Bucks')
team1_abbr = team1_search[0]['abbreviation']

team2_search = teams.find_teams_by_full_name('Lakers')
team2_abbr = team2_search[0]['abbreviation']

with open('nba_stats/stats/data/1949-2018_officialBoxScore.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        seasons = []
        for row in csv_dict_reader:
            seasons.append(row['season'])

        set_res = set(seasons)
        seasons = (list(set_res))

season1 = '2019-20'
season2 = '2019-20'

if season1 == '2019-20' or season2 == '2019-20':
    with open('nba_stats/stats/data/2019-20_officialBoxScore.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        if season1 == '2019-20':
            team1PTS = []
            oppt1PTS = []
            for row in csv_dict_reader:         
                if row['teamAbbr'] == team1_abbr and row['seasonType'] == 'Regular':
                    team1PTS.append(float(row['teamPTS']))
                    oppt1PTS.append(float(row['opptPTS']))
                        
                elif row['opptAbbr'] == team1_abbr and row['seasonType'] == 'Regular':
                    team1PTS.append(float(row['opptPTS']))
                    oppt1PTS.append(float(row['teamPTS']))

        if season2 == '2019-20':
            team2PTS = []
            oppt2PTS = []
            #I'm pretty sure this for loop is the issue after a couple of tests
            for row in csv_dict_reader:   
                if row['teamAbbr'] == team2_abbr and row['seasonType'] == 'Regular':
                    team2PTS.append(float(row['teamPTS']))
                    oppt2PTS.append(float(row['opptPTS']))

                elif row['opptAbbr'] == team2_abbr and row['seasonType'] == 'Regular':
                    team2PTS.append(float(row['opptPTS']))
                    oppt2PTS.append(float(row['teamPTS']))
```

Desired Behaviour

```
Bucks: 98
Lakers: 117
```

Error

```
Warning: Mean of empty slice.
  return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
C:\Users\panos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:161: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
C:\Users\panos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:216: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
C:\Users\panos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:185: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:209: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
e 106, in <module>
    team1_sim_pts = int(round((rnd.gauss(team1_mean, team1_std) + rnd.gauss(opp2_mean, opp2_std))) / 2)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `for` loop everything in the file has been read, so there's nothing left for the second loop to read. Starting a new `for` loop doesn't reset the file back to the beginning. You need to seek back to the beginning of the file before trying to read it again.

```
        if season2 == '2019-20':
            team2PTS = []
            oppt2PTS = []
            csv_file.seek(0) # rewind to beginning of file
            for row in csv_dict_reader:   
                if row['teamAbbr'] == team2_abbr and row['seasonType'] == 'Regular':
                    team2PTS.append(float(row['teamPTS']))
                    oppt2PTS.append(float(row['opptPTS']))

                elif row['opptAbbr'] == team2_abbr and row['seasonType'] == 'Regular':
                    team2PTS.append(float(row['opptPTS']))
                    oppt2PTS.append(float(row['teamPTS']))
```